# How to input operator in python?

Tags: python

#Faulty calculator

I want to make a calculator that give the wrong answer of my given question and
give all correct answer of other question

```py
operator = input("Enter operator")

number1 = int(input("Enter your number 1"))

number2 = int(input("Enter your number 2"))

if operator == * and number1 == (45) and number2 == (3):

    print(number1operatornumber2: 555)

elif operator == + and number1 == 56 and number2 == 9:

    print(number1operatornumber2: 77)

elif operator == / and number1 == (56) and number2 == 6:

    print(number1operatornumber2: 4)

else :
    
    print(number1 opertor number2: number1operatornumber2)
```

In my program comming like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yklE.png)

Comment: Please include the stack trace as text, not as an image. What do you think the problem might be?

Comment: First of all, Python `input` takes everything as a string.

Comment: First of all what you have written is not valid code. `+ = \ ` all should be inside qoutes like "+".  What is the difference between  "given question" and "other question". And if understand correctly do you want to give a wrong answer for each input? Why

Comment: you need to check operator as `operator =='*'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take operators as inputs, then you must check every single operator. Here's an edited version of your code that works a little bit.

```
operator = input("Enter operator: ")

number1 = int(input("Enter your number 1"))

number2 = int(input("Enter your number 2: "))

if operator == '*' and number1 == (45) and number2 == (3):

    print(f'{number1 * number2} : 555')

elif operator == '+' and number1 == 56 and number2 == 9:

    print(f'{number1 + number2} : 77')

elif operator == '/' and number1 == (56) and number2 == 6:

    print(f'{number1 / number2} : 4')

#else :

#    print(number1 opertor number2: number1operatornumber2)
```

Notice the last one. Here you don't know what the operator could be. Hence, you can't apply any operation on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
operator = input("Enter operator")
number1 = int(input("Enter your number 1"))
number2 = int(input("Enter your number 2"))

if (operator == '*' and number1 == 45 and number2 == 3):

    print(number1,operator,number2, 555)

elif (operator == '+' and number1 == 56 and number2 == 9):

    print(number1, operator, number2, 77)

elif(operator == '/' and number1 == 56 and number2 == 6):

    print(number1, operator, number2, 4)

else :
    
    print(number1, operator, number2, number1,operator,number2)
```

Update the code by correcting the syntax errors as above. Variables should be seperated by `,` in the print statement and use quotes to compare operators